# Change Color of Entry Underline or Remove this Color

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI Entry, I wanted to change the Color of the Underline in an Entry in Code-Behind.

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

======= Edited with implementation of Answer below ======

Hint: I tried the answer below with an own BorderlessEntryControl which was derived from an Entry Control. There, at least the Placehodler-TextColor got lost. Maybe more Properties

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls

Comment: There is an active issue on github https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7906

Comment: Thanks for the update - long time opened already 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For remove the underline on the android, you can add the following code into the MauiProgram.cs:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(Entry), (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
#endif
        });
```

And on the windows platform, you can put the following code into the /Platforms/Windows/App.xaml:

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused">0</Thickness>
 </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

And there is no underline on the ios.

**update 1：**

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. I also added something for iOS:
```#if __ANDROID__
                handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
#elif __IOS__
                handler.PlatformView.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.Clear;
                handler.PlatformView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;
#endif```

Comment: I tried with a BorderlessEntryControl which was derived from an Entry Control and at least here the Placeholder TextColor from the standard Entry got lost (see screenshot above). Is this normal?

Comment: On the windows platform or all the platforms?

Comment: When I test on the windows and android, the Placehodler-TextColor didn't change.

Comment: SetBackgroundColor becomes a problem when you also want to have different background color for entries

Comment: I tested in on my Android Emulator **Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 API 33)**

Comment: I also tested on the Pixel 3a - API 33 emulator. And my project target sdk is .net 7.0.

Comment: You can check the result image in my answer. @OXO

Answer (score 5):

For MAUI .Net 8.0

```
handler.PlatformView.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I haven’t switched over to .NET 8 so far, but good option when I do it

Comment: Where do we put this?

Comment: App.Xaml.cs Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(Entry), (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            handler.PlatformView.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
#endif
        });

Answer (score 3):

in Platform for Android, needs to add the handler, looks like this:

```
 protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
 {
     // Remove Entry control underline
     Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("NoUnderline", (h, v) =>
     {
         h.PlatformView.BackgroundTintList =
             Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Colors.Transparent.ToAndroid());
     });

     return MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Maui .Net 8, go to **Platforms** **->** **Android** **->** **MainApplication.cs**
inside **MainApplication** method add this

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace CarListApp.Maui;
[Application]
public class MainApplication : MauiApplication
{
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownership)
        : base(handle, ownership)
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(Entry), (handler, view) =>
        {
            if (view is Entry)
            {
                // Remove underline
                handler.PlatformView.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);

                // Change placeholder text color
                handler.PlatformView.SetHintTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Red));
            }
        });
    }

    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
}
```

In your **xaml** file

```xaml
<VerticalStackLayout 
    Spacing="25"
    Padding="20,10"
    VerticalOptions="Center">

    <Frame Padding="0" Margin="-5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" HasShadow="True" 
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" MinimumWidthRequest="290">
           
        <Entry x:Name="Username" Placeholder="Enter Username" Margin="10,0" />
    </Frame>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

**Result**

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4HlZ.png)

---

**To change underline color:**

Go to **Platforms** -> **Android** -> **Resources** -> **values** -> In **colors.xml** change **colorAccent** to the color you want.